# Laravel 5 - how to authenticate without email confirmation?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I'm creating a simple authentication system in Laravel 5.  I have authentication code written in Laravel 4 that I'm using as a foundation.

My problem is,

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'confirmed' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` =
>   myemail@gmail.com and `confirmed` = 1 limit 1)

It looks like Laravel is looking to see if my email was verified.  But I do not need to implement a sign-up and verification process for this application.  My question is, how do I tell laravel *not* to worry about email confirmation?

My authentication code looks like this:

```
public function postAuthenticate()
{
    // Fetch posted credentials

    $email = \Request::input('email');
    $password = \Request::input('password');
    $remember = \Request::has('_remember');

    $credentials = [
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => $password,
        'confirmed' => 1
    ];

    // Attempt to log in user
    if (\Auth::attempt($credentials, $remember))
    {
        return \Redirect::intended('dashboard');
    }

    // If this code was reached, it means that the user failed to authenticated.  
    // In this case, redirect back to the login page with errors.

    $messages = new Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
    $messages->add('Authentication Error', 'Sign in failed.');


    return \Redirect::to('/login')
        ->withInput()   
        ->with('errors', $messages);
}
```

And my user model looks like:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

}
```

And finally, my user table migration is:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove `'confirmed' => 1` from `$credentials`.

For example:

```
$credentials = [
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => $password
];
```

Comment: Such an obvious oversight on my part!  Thanks!

Comment: best for me! is my first answer! ;)